# In IOS, how do you play parts of an audio clip out of order?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio

Say I have 1 audio clip, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."  How do I play segments of the audio clip.  For example, if I want to be able to skip the words "quick" and "lazy" during playback.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AVAudioPlayer Framework provided in iOS>2.2

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer play];
```

the audioplayer gives you the ability to set it to certain points where to start playing,
for example

```
[audioPlayer setCurrentTime:0.6];
```

[Apple developer docs for Audioplayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)